# System Exception - Input stream is not at the beginning position in Kentico

Tags: c#, .net, kentico

I am working on a Kentico project where I have to integrate MetaScan into Kentico. I am trying to send a HttpPosted file through the method `callMetaScan(CMSFileUpload.PostedFile)` and I have the following `callMetaScan` method

```
private void callMetaScan(System.Web.HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile)
{ 
    string strDate = string.Format("{0} GMT", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest myReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(myURI);
    myReq.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);

    myReq.Method = "POST";

    byte[] myBytes = new byte[httpPostedFile.InputStream.Length];
    //Read the file into the byte array.
    httpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);

    myReq.ContentLength = myBytes.Length;

    myReq.ContentType = httpPostedFile.ContentType;

    System.IO.Stream PostData = (System.IO.Stream)myReq.GetRequestStream();
    PostData.Write(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);

    PostData.Close();

    System.Net.HttpWebResponse Response2 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

    //throw new Exception(GetString("1"));

    System.IO.StreamReader SR = default(System.IO.StreamReader);
    SR = new System.IO.StreamReader(Response2.GetResponseStream());
    string rslt = SR.ReadToEnd();
    SR.Close();

    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlRslt = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xmlRslt.LoadXml(rslt);

    //if no final_scan_result, then save a copy of the xml and email us.
    if (xmlRslt.SelectSingleNode(pathstring) != null)
    {
        int finalScanResultCode = Int32.Parse(xmlRslt.SelectSingleNode(pathstring).InnerText);

    }
    else
    {
        //Send Email about the XML
         Response.Write(“Unable to scan file.”);            
    }
}
```

I am getting this following error message

> [AttachmentInfo.EnsureBinaryData]: Input stream is not at the beginning position.
>   Exception type: System.Exception
>   Stack Trace: 
>   at CMS.DocumentEngine.AttachmentInfo.LoadDataFromStream()
>   at CMS.DocumentEngine.AttachmentInfo.get_AttachmentBinary()
>   at CMS.DocumentEngine.AttachmentInfo..ctor(HttpPostedFile postedFile, Int32 documentId, Guid attachmentGuid)
>   at CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(TreeNode node, String guidColumnName, Guid attachmentGuid, Guid groupGuid, Object file, TreeProvider tree, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 maxSideSize)
>   at CMSModules_Content_Controls_Attachments_DirectFileUploader_DirectFileUploaderControl.HandleAttachmentUpload(Boolean fieldAttachment)

When I am trying to create a new response on this line 
`System.Net.HttpWebResponse Response2 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse()`  it is giving me this error.

I have checked that initially ucFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Position was 0 but after the line ucFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length) I see a different value

Please suggest how I may fix this. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I need help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you read the data from the posted file here:

```
//Read the file into the byte array.
httpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);
```

Then also, after this method somewhere, Kentico also tries to read from the post data from the same reference `httpPostedFile`.

A good practice when using input streams that others may use later is to set the stream's read pointer back to the beginning, ie:

```
httpPostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
```